# Program Crashing while trying to open a .txt file

Tags: c++, file-io, linked-list

When I try to run my program it crashes right of the start. The problem is my input from file, I can write to the file fine. Can someone explain why this code wouldn't work??

```
StringList::StringList()
{
  pTop=NULL;
  pBottom=NULL;

  ifstream in;
  in.open("read.txt");

  StringListNode * pCurrent;
  pCurrent = new StringListNode;
  pCurrent = pTop;

  while(!in.eof())  //reads it till the end of file
  {
    in >> pCurrent->data;
    pCurrent = pCurrent->pNext;
  }
  in.close();
}
```

This Output to the file works fine. I thought I would just include it.

```
StringList::~StringList()
{
  ofstream out;
  out.open("read.txt");

  StringListNode * pCurrent;
  pCurrent = new StringListNode;
  pCurrent = pTop;
  while(pCurrent != 0)  
  {
    out << pCurrent->data << endl;
    pCurrent = pCurrent->pNext;
  }
  out.close();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pCurrent = pTop;` Why do you assign this here?  This makes `pCurrent` null pointer. Please remove or fix.

I'm confused with your code:

```
pCurrent = new StringListNode; // Allocate new memory and point at it
pCurrent = pTop; // Make pCurrent point at same thing as pTop
```

You assign to `pCurrent` twice. `pTop` looks like a data member, perhaps you meant in constructor:

```
pCurrent = new StringListNode; // Allocate new memory and point at it
pCurrent->pNext = nullptr; // Assign null to next pointer
pTop = pCurrent; // Make pTop point at new memory
```

and in destructor remove `pCurrent = new StringListNode;` because it does not do anything.

When outputting, you check `pCurrent != 0`, but you do not check for null when reading. Probably `pCurrent` is null pointer.

Also, please read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). Your loop should be:

```
while(pCurrent && (in >> pCurrent->data)) 
{
   pCurrent = pCurrent->pNext;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you that fixed my crashing issue, but it is not displaying the text from the file.

Comment: Please remove `pCurrent = pTop;`, why do you do this assignment?

Comment: ahh, That was frustrating me beyond compare, It works now. Thank you so much.

Comment: @GiBiT09: Does it read the whole file? It looks like it only reads from the file one time. Perhaps you need to build the linked list by allocating new memory in the loop, but I will leave that for you to figure out.

Comment: Yea it only displays the first one in the file. So your if i make a  pointer inside the loop like StringListNode * pNew; pNew = pNew->pNext;??

Comment: Ah just tried that, that makes it display only the last item in the list.

Comment: @GiBiT09: No, you probably want ` pCurrent->pNext = new StringListNode; pCurrent = pCurrent->pNext;`. However, you should learn about how pointers work better.